# how to make same slider in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

i already made a slider with image thumbnails, i want to use same another one in my page but, when i use same code in html only first one is working. this is what i wants to make [this is my page  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXClC.png)

```
<script>

    function changeImage(event) {
  event = event || window.event;

  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;

  if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
  }
}

</script>
```

html

```
<img height="250" width="500" style="border:3px solid grey"  src="images/g1.jpg" id="mainImage"></img/>
<br />

<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event)">
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g1.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g2.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g3.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g4.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g5.jpg" />
</div>
<br />


<img height="250" width="500" style="border:3px solid grey"  src="images/g1.jpg" id="mainImage"></img/>
<br />

<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event)">
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g1.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g2.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g3.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g4.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g5.jpg" />
</div>  

    <br><br>
```

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imgstyle {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

.imgstyle + .imgstyle {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code, the slider does not work. can you please share the minimal working code! use the [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8Ltu7az/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting element by ID, this will return the 1st match
 document.getElementById("mainImage");
That why it is working for 1st one only
Instead use

```
 <div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event, 0)"> 
 <div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event, 1)"> //for second one
```

Js

```
function changeImage(event, a) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;
  if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("mainImage")[a].src  = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
   }
  }
```

Also change I'd of main IMG to class

```
  <img height="250" width="500" style="border:3px solid grey"  src="images/g1.jpg" class="mainImage"></img/>
```